# How can I save Authorization Code And Realm ID to gain Access and Refresh Tokens?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm a newbie working on a Ruby on Rails app to communicate with quickbooks Via version 3 API. I need help to save my Authorization Code And Realm ID from quickbooks and use them to get access and refresh tokens. I am following both [this guide](https://minimul.com/integrating-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-the-version-3-api-part-1.html) and this [ruby gem by ruckus](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) and I'm stuck. I can connect to quickbooks authorize link, sign in and then redirect to my applications redirect URL. I can see my Authorization Code And Realm Id through the redirect URL. It's something like `http://localhost:3000/vendors?code=HERE_IS_MY_AUTH_CODE&state=STATE_CODE&realmId=AND_MY_REALM_ID` problem is I can see these codes on this URL but I can't obtain them. And even if I do I don't know what to do next to get tokens with these Auth code and Realm ID.

I've tried to create a table as shown in the gem guide but I don't know where to put these lines;

```
 qb_access_token = quickbooks_credentials.access_token
 qb_refresh_token = quickbooks_credentials.refresh_token

 access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth2_client, qb_access_token, refresh_token: qb_refresh_token)
```

My Table;

```
class CreateQuickbooksCredentials < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :quickbooks_credentials do |t|
      t.text :access_token
      t.datetime :access_token_expires_at
      t.text :refresh_token
      t.datetime :refresh_token_expires_at
      t.text :realm_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My Initializer;

```
oauth_params = {
site: "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
authorize_url: "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
token_url: "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
}
$oauth2_client = OAuth2::Client.new("MY_CLIENT_ID", 
"MY_CLIENT_SECRET", oauth_params)

Quickbooks.sandbox_mode = true
```

My Controller Actions;

```
def authenticate
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/vendors"
grant_url = $oauth2_client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: redirect_uri, response_type: "code", state: SecureRandom.hex(12), scope: "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting")
redirect_to grant_url
end
```

```
  def oauth_callback
    if params[:state].present?
      # use the state value to retrieve from your backend any information you need to identify the customer in your system
      redirect_uri = quickbooks_oauth_callback_url
      if resp = oauth2_client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], redirect_uri: redirect_uri)
        # save your tokens here.
        quickbooks_credentials.update_attributes(access_token: resp.token, refresh_token: resp.refresh_token, realm_id: params[:realmId])
      end
    end
  end
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

> problem is I can see these codes on this URL but I can't obtain them

The Authorization Code Flow process for the OAuth 2 protocol implies that the Authorization Code is a temporary code that is valid for a very short time and is intended only for receiving an AccessToken and RefreshToken. It is impossible to reuse it and there is **no need to store** it. If you need to get a new Access Token, then use either Refresh Token (https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/), or go through the Authorization Code Flow

Comment: I don't want to store it. I just need to use it in order to get access and refresh tokens. I am not trying to reuse it or anything, it will automatically expire and when it does it will be replaced by the new one from the new URL. I can't refresh a token that I don't have in the first place. First I need to get it and to get it I need to obtain required params.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have understood your question. You have an 'oauth_callback' method that will be called by Quickbooks after successful authorization. As a request parameter, there will be an authorization code that you will send there via the `oauth2_client. auth_code method.get_token` and get tokens from response. As specified https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby#getting-started--initiating-authentication-flow-with-intuit you can save tokens in the designated fields.

Comment: Authorization was successful but when I check `QuickbooksCredentials` it returns `nil`. It needs to contain `access_token` `refresh_token` `realm_id` parameters. If I can't send those tokens to the quickbooks, I can't make API calls. Or am I overthinking it I don't know. Point is I don't know where else to go from here even after I obtain or workaround those tokens, I don't know how exactly to use them. I am really new at this stuff and guides are either very old or not descriptive as I need. BTW thank you for tolerating me I'm sure I'm making you facepalm right now.

Comment: how do you define 'quickbooks_credentials' in controller?

Comment: Should I use something like; `quickbooks_credentials = QuickbookCredentials.new` in my controller?

Comment: You're better of using something like QuickbooksCredentials.create(access_token: resp.token, refresh_token: resp.refresh_token, realm_id: params[:realmId]) directly in the oauth_callback method.

Comment: or use before_action to define the @quickbooks_credentials variable and use @quickbooks_credentials.update(...) in the oauth_callback method (not update_attributes, it not save model).

Comment: Tried both, didn't work. Funny, I can see the parameters clearly in server response on terminal; `Parameters: {"code"=>"AB11625215XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXwKg3ckC", "state"=>"cb00XXXXXXXXXXXXX1a4", "realmId"=>"462XXXXXXXXXXXXX840"}` just don't know how to get to them and use them.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you're getting the auth code response from Intuit, you've already done the hard part - the rest will be easy provided you're comfortable extracting values from a JSON object and using them to initialize a different object.

Have you been able to successfully initialize any object in Ruby? If so, can you initialize your *quickbooks_credentials* object with test values (rather than values from the response body)? Once you've got that working, can you initialize the *quickbooks_credentials* object using a test JSON object?

When you can answer 'yes' to that last question, you should find you can -just as easily- repeat the process with the QuickBooks Authorization code. If after all that you're still having problems, please follow up here. And don't give up; one way or another, you will get there!